# Categories menu using JQuery on a static page

Tags: jquery, html, menu, navigation, static-html

Here's my case:

I'm building a classic layout with a side menu on the left with a list of categories and a list of tiles on the main wrapper that get filtered depending on what category the user choses.

Now, the page is a static site so all content is already there (no need of Json, AJAX or anything fancy) and each "tile" can have more than one category attached, so I think a simple Jquery script should do the trick. Having said that, I'm quite clueless when it comes to JQuery and though my code works very nicely I feel it's not very optimized.

Could someone lend a hand and maybe teach me a couple of things? I would really appreciated it.

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6hmnk5od/

And here's the code:

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Reset
  $('.cat-tree-reset').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('.tile-item').show();
  });

  // Show/hide projects
  $('.cat-1').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-1-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-1-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-2').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-2-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-2-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-3').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-3-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-3-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-4').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-4-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-4-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-5').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-5-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-5-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-6').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-6-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-6-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-7').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-7-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-7-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-8').click(function() {
    $('.cat-active').removeClass('cat-active');
    $(this).addClass('cat-active');
    $('.tiles-list').children('li.tile-item, :not(.cat-8-item)').hide();
    $('.tiles-list').children('.cat-8-item').show();
  });

});
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="categories-list">
  <label>Categories</label>

  <div class="cat-tree-reset">Clear</div>

  <ul class="cat-tree-wrapper">
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-1">Category 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-2">Category 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-3">Category 3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-4">Category 4</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-5">Category 5</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-6">Category 6</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-7">Category 7</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="cat-tree-item cat-8">Category 8</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<hr>


<ul class="row tile-card-wrapper tiles-list" id="container">
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-7-item cat-2-item">
    Tile A
  </li>
  <li class="cat-2-item tile-item cat-3-item cat-7-item cat-6-item">
    Tile B
  </li>
  <li class="cat-1-item tile-item cat-3-item cat-6-item cat-7-item">
    Tile C
  </li>
  <li class="cat-2-item tile-item cat-7-item">
    Tile D
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-6-item cat-7-item">
    Tile E
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-6-item">
    Tile F
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-5-item">
    Tile G
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-1-item cat-3-item">
    Tile H
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-4-item cat-7-item">
    Tile I
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-6-item cat-7-item">
    Tile J
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-7-item cat-5-item">
    Tile K
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-7-item cat-2-item">
    Tile L
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-6-item cat-7-item">
    Tile M
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-6-item cat-7-item">
    Tile N
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-1-item cat-4-item">
    Tile O
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-7-item cat-8-item">
    Tile P
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item">
    Tile Q
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-1-item">
    Tile R
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item cat-3-item cat-4-item cat-8-item">
    Tile S
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make your code substantially shorter and easier to maintain.

HTML:
I have removed a lot of classes, and added a single data attribute to each span, data-cat, which is just the category number.

The tile items themselves no longer have multiple classes, but a single data-cats attribute which contains an array of the categories they belong to.

```
<div class="categories-list" >
<label>Categories</label>

<div class="cat-tree-reset">Clear</div>

<ul class="cat-tree-wrapper">
  <li>
    <span data-cat="1">Category 1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-cat="2">Category 2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-cat="3">Category 3</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-cat="4">Category 4</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-cat="5">Category 5</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-cat="6">Category 6</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-cat="7">Category 7</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span data-cat="8">Category 8</span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>


<ul class="row tile-card-wrapper tiles-list" id="container">
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[2,3,7]">
    Tile A        
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[2,3,6,7]">
    Tile B
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[1,3,6,7]">
    Tile C
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[2,7]">
    Tile D
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[3,6,7]">
    Tile E
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[6]">
    Tile F
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[5]">
    Tile G
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[3]">
    Tile H
  </li>
  <li class="tile-item" data-cats="[4,8]">
    Tile I
  </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:
We are just putting one click handler on all the clickable spans, and using their new data-cat attribute to filter the tile-items.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Reset
  $('.cat-tree-reset').click(function() {
      $('.tile-item').show();
  });

  $('.cat-tree-wrapper > li > span').click(function() {
    //get the data-cat value for the span we clicked on
    var category = $(this).data('cat');

    // hide all tile items
    $('.tile-item').hide();

    // the function passed to filter returns true if the current tile item
    // contains the category we obtained earlier, or false if it doesn't
    // leaving us with only the tile items in that category, which we show.
    $('.tile-item').filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('cats').includes(category);
    }).show();
  });      
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/6hmnk5od/1/)

Comment: Wow that is perfect! Thanks a lot @Alex!

Comment: I really need to step up my JS game (that right now is pretty much none), things like the _filter_ function and trying to use variables more proactively... Really helpful stuff Alex Young.

Comment: A future improvement I'll try to work on in the future is making the list be generated using the array of available categories on the "tiles".

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.  If you can learn the map, reduce and filter functions well, then you will be able to solve a lot of problems with them.

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned - [browser support for Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is not complete, so if IE support is an issue for you then you will need to use a different method (e.g. indexOf) or a polyfill.

Comment: I have a fiddle with dynamic menu generation from the tiles - have a go yourself and let me know if you want to see my approach